# Какие могут быть причины JSONException: End of input at character 0 of?

Tags: java, android, json

Есть такой код:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public static String LOG_TAG = "my_log";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new ParseTask().execute();
    }

    private class ParseTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String resultJson = "";

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // получаем данные с внешнего ресурса
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://androiddocs.ru/api/friends.json");

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }

                resultJson = buffer.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return resultJson;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String strJson) {
            super.onPostExecute(strJson);
            // выводим целиком полученную json-строку
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, strJson);

            JSONObject dataJsonObj = null;
            String secondName = "";

            try {
                dataJsonObj = new JSONObject(strJson);
                JSONArray friends = dataJsonObj.getJSONArray("friends");

                // 1. достаем инфо о втором друге - индекс 1
                JSONObject secondFriend = friends.getJSONObject(1);
                secondName = secondFriend.getString("name");
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Второе имя: " + secondName);

                // 2. перебираем и выводим контакты каждого друга
                for (int i = 0; i < friends.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject friend = friends.getJSONObject(i);

                    JSONObject contacts = friend.getJSONObject("contacts");

                    String phone = contacts.getString("mobile");
                    String email = contacts.getString("email");
                    String skype = contacts.getString("skype");

                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "phone: " + phone);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "email: " + email);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "skype: " + skype);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

в логе выводится

> org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of.

Может быть причина в Android Studio?

Comment: По всей вероятности с сервера приходит пустой json, хотя через браузер он открывается. В манифесте интернет включен.

Comment: судя по выводу, на вход JSON-конвертера реально приходит пустая строка

Comment: `через браузер он открывается` - `User-Agent`, или может другие хедеры?

Comment: В этой части кода нет ни каких ошибок.

Comment: Покажите строку, которые вы с сервера получаете.

Comment: Метки (теги) нужны для того, чтобы выделить основные моменты ВОПРОСА, по которым другие пользователи быстрее смогут найти решение аналогичной проблемы, а не для демонстрации собственных предпочтений в выборе IDE. Вопрос никак не связан с проблемами при работе IDE Android Studio и этот тег в вопросе не нужен.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка может встречаться из-за отсутствия подключения к сети.